# What is the best server manufacturer for Debian/Ubuntu server?

Tags: ubuntu, debian

I am looking for rackable servers that will run on Debian or Ubuntu Server with a manufactuer that provide .deb files for the systems tools (Like OpenManage or Insight Manager).

It looks like HP provide .deb for its last servers, but Dell does not...

What manufacturer do you have on your Debian/Ubuntu server ? What do you recommend ?
Thank you ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

speaking from perspective of poweredge user running mostly debians:

do you really want to run this heavy management thing on each and every server you have?

truth is you don't really need most of those fancy tools. you do need raid monitoring - but that one you can usually get as binary package from actual raid vendor [ lsi in most cases for dell/ibm/hp ]. you might want to monitor via ipmi general health status - but this will be vendor independent as long as ipmi functionality is provided by motherboard/addon management card.

and [omsa](http://linux.dell.com/monitoring.shtml) for dell is available for debian too: [here](https://subtrac.sara.nl/oss/omsa_2_deb#version6).

Comment: That what I would like is a software that allow me to monitor all the physical aspect of the server like fan status, temperatures, power consumption (On 90% of the servers, it's not available via ACPI/APM) and alert me by mail in case of problems, and I think using IPMI needs the installation of a IPMI driver specific to each server (not sure), another advantage is OpenManage and Insight Manager allows me to centralize that in one place, and also its sometime the only way to slow down the fans (on some HP/Dell servers, the fans are stuck to maximum speed if the health driver is not installed)

Comment: i'm monitoring dell DRACs [ management cards ] over lan using regular/generic ipmitool. all is checked by nagios which generates mails. fans are checked too..

Answer (score 1):

The starting point is to check which one support officially the Ubuntu distribution you plan to deploy on your server model.

I think that will be your first criteria of choice, then look on the canonical website to see which hardware they support.

HP seems to have a page on the Ubuntu website, I suppose you can find the equivalent for DELL and IBM.

http://www.ubuntu.com/partners/hp

http://www.ubuntu.com/partners/ibm

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The normal distros will probably run on any normal brand name server, but unless you purchased the OS with the machine, you can forget about support out of the box.

I'm pretty sure this is the case with all the vendors, but with Dell, if you run an unsupported OS, you simply are directed to a download link of a diagnostic LiveCD, and if all tests there pass, you'll probably be on your own, since those would eliminate a hardware fault. If the server is bought with the OS as OEM on the other hand, you'll get qualified Linux support from the software support escalation team, who ultimately have a channel to open support tickets with the software manufacturer.